# What is the Optimal strategy to win in this game I made?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

So I made up this game, but I'm not able to find a good strategy to always win.

It's very similar to the [original 3×3 Tic-Tac-Toe](https://www.wikihow.com/Play-Tic-Tac-Toe); but with changes.

So you draw a 5×5 board. Then each player takes turns putting a cross and circle. We then count the "scores".

[This is a completed game that I drew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2IEO.png). The scores are made by counting every 3-in-a-row strike. So for example in the top row, cross player gets 1 point.

You then do the counting horizontally, vertically, and both ways diagonally; for each row, column and diagonal.

For a 4-in-a-row, you get two points, as you can look at it as 2 different 3-in-a-rows. Similarly, a 5-in-a-row would get 3 points.

In the example game, cross wins as it get 9 whereas circle gets only 7.

I play this a lot; but it's always hard to tell where to put your next move. I've noticed that starting first gives you a significant advantage. To compensate for this, I lower the points of the player who started first by one.

This can obviously be extended to further dimensions, but I would like an answer only for a 5×5 grid.

So what's the optimal strategy?

Thanks in advance!

Side note: I'm learning programming ATM, so if someone knows what they're doing, can they also simulate this game in a program? I'd be really grateful if someone does.

Comment: There are less than $3^{25}\approx 2^{40}\approx 10^{12}$ positions, so someone could solve the game by brute force. (*For example, Connect Four has more positions and was solved by brute force in 1995. - see [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four#Mathematical_solution).*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TLDR - Assuming the "one point less to X" rule, the game is a draw.**

For example, if X starts in the center and both players play optimal moves, then the following unique position (up to symmetry) can always be forced by X:

[image]

were no matter what X plays on the next two moves, X will end up with one point more than O. *(This is a draw if you lower X's points.)*

After every move by X (while forcing this position), O has only one correct response!

**That is, every move by O can be forced by X.** (*If O makes just a single mistake, X will have multiple ways to get an advantage of more than just one point.*)

---

**Solution**

I have solved the game computationally.

If first player X has penalty to start with 1 point less (equivalently, if second player O has compensation to start with 1 point more), **then the game is a draw under optimal play.** Otherwise, first player wins by 1 point (or more points if second player doesn't play optimally).

I have used [alpha-beta pruning with transposition tables](http://people.csail.mit.edu/plaat/mtdf.html#abmem) for search and bitboards to encode positions. After putting together some quick `c++` code, it took me less than one hour to solve the game. *(I've shared my initial code on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/261359/105332) and an updated version on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@DexterousAlpaca/CumulativeTicTacToe5by5).)*

**Below are example games using optimal strategy**. (*To punish non-optimal moves, you can run my code and explore the variations. Note that it can take multiple minutes if you evaluate a position with only a few pieces on the board.*)

---

**Terminology**

Given a 5 by 5 grid, call a square "adjacent" if it can be reached by one vertical or horizontal step, unless specified otherwise.

Let "advantage" be the number of raw points player X has more than player O. Raw meaning that we are ignoring the penalty aka compensation. To account for the penalty aka compensation, simply subtract one from the advantage.

---

**First move**

The optimal first move for X is to start in the center. This is the only first move after which X can still force a nonnegative advantage even if they make a mistake (plays a random move) on their second move!

The second best first move for X is to play in one of four adjacent squares to the center. Even if O follows up by playing in the center, X can still force positive advantage in this scenario.

The worst first move for X is to play in a corner or in a square adjacent to a corner. Then, O can force negative advantage after playing in the center.

That is, under optimal play, X can secure an advantage of $1$ by starting in any of the five central squares. But, the center itself is the best first move as it forces O to play more precisely.

After X plays the first move in the center, the only good move for O is to then play in one of the four adjacent squares. Otherwise, X can force an advantage greater than $1$, which is either $2$ or $3$.

[image]

---

**Optimal game**

WLOG (due to symmetry), the optimal game starts as follows: (*X takes center and one of the four adjacent squares not opposite the one that O took, while O takes any adjacent square and then one opposite to the one that X took.*)

[image]

The advantage that is forced under optimal play is shown on the *left image*. That is, X can continue to play into any of the squares marked with the advantage of $1$. The *right image* shows the number of different optimal responses by O if  X plays there. (Lower number in the *right image* means O needs to be more precise).

Therefore, one can argue that squares containing $1$ on both images are the best optimal moves. It turns out that if X picks one of these two squares, then O must play in the other of the two. That is, we get one of the following two positions depending on what X picks.

1. X continues up-adjacent to center.

[image]

2. X continues left-down-adjacent to center.

[image]

Where again, in both cases, X can play in any of the $1$'s in the *left image*, where again $1$'s in the *right image* are arguably the best as they force O to play an exact move.

In both cases, X has two best optimal moves. But, in the first case, both best optimal moves are equivalent due to symmetry. This leads to three possible optimal games.

1. X plays in 2nd square on the main diagonal, in the previous first case.

[image]

2. X makes 3-in-a-row on main antidiagonal, in previous second case.

[image]

3. X threatens to make double 3-in-a-row, in previous second case.

[image]

Notice that in the new third case, X now has a forced move and needs to play precisely from now on to keep the advantage of $1$! So maybe, picking a move that gives O least many options is not always the best optimal move.

In the new first case, whatever optimal move X picks, O will still have multiple optimal choices. I won't go into detail into these games as it starts branching a lot.

Only in the new second case, X has moves that give no choice to O. Expanding on these two choices from X, we have the following two "best" optimal games.

1. X connects 3-in-a-row vertically, in new second case.

[image]

2. X connects 3-in-a-row horizontally, in new second case.

[image]

Continuing to expand this newer second case, we have:

1. X chooses to make 3-in-a-row.

[image]

2. X chooses to block 3-in-a-row threatened by O.

[image]

The first option is better than the second, so expanding on it:

1. X threatens two 3-in-a-row's.

[image]

2. X threatens one 3-in-a-row.

[image]

The first option is again clearly better, and now it is not hard to also see that the first $1$ is the better continuation for the first option. This leads to one "best" optimal game:

[image]

Now again, it is not hard to see that $1$ in the bottom left corner is the best optimal move, which leads to the following position.

[image]

Once again, the $1$ in the last row is the best optimal move, leading to:

[image]

And now finally, X can force the best optimal position:

[image]

Finally, whatever X plays on next two moves, the advantage of $1$ is kept.

Notice that every move by O was forced so far.

That is, this unique position (up to symmetry), can always be forced by X!

---

You can verify all this and also explore various branches, alternatives and responses yourself, using my code that I linked. *Btw, to increase the speed of solving early positions, you may want to start saving important optimal moves and responses.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124960/discussion-on-answer-by-vepir-what-is-the-optimal-strategy-to-win-in-this-game-i).